# Excel macro - counting inserted rows

Tags: excel, count, vba

I'm copying data from one sheet to another and I have a universal counter, x.

```
    x = 2
    Sheets("Info").Select
    Range("B2:B6").Copy Destination:=Sheets("GreatIdea").Range("A" & x)
    x = x + 1
```

So I insert 5 rows and the following fields get data; A2, A3, A4, A5, A6.

```
    x is currently 3
    Sheets("Info").Select
    Range("B10").Copy Destination:=Sheets("GreatIdea").Range("A" & x)
```

So now 1 row gets inserted, but cell A3 will get its data overwritten. How can I add 'x' up with the number of fields added in the previous copy. So 'x' becomes 7?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Rows.Count

```
x = x + Range("B2:B6").Rows.Count
```

Comment: is there a way to extend it so lets say B2:B5 contains data, but B6 is empty, I don't want it to use B6 in the count. Is this possible?

Comment: Hmm... I can't think of a one-liner that will do it, but it will be possible with a seperate function. Use a 'for each' loop, and check for vbNullString